# How to allow SSH from internet when it is forwarded to a non-standard port

Tags: server, 13.10, ssh, firewall

I'm configuring a virtual firewall using Shorewall and have a rule to forward the external port 2222 to internal port 22:

```
DNAT    inet    lan:192.168.1.2:22    tcp    2222
```

where 192.168.1.2 is the IP address of the firewall. But it doesn't work!

I don't want to allow SSH directly (port 22) like this:

```
SSH(ACCEPT)    inet    $FW
```

How do I make the firewall accept redirected SSH?

Comment: Please tag also by `shorewall`. AU is missing this tag.

Comment: you can add another line: 'Port 2222' in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and ssh will listen to that port as well

Comment: @jet: thanks! makes sense. and works, too. please post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add another line: 'Port 2222' in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and ssh will listen to that port as well